# How to define a protocol to be used as a type

Tags: swift

I saw this working code (Swift 1.2)

```
var itemToPrint : Printable
itemToPrint = 105.0
println( itemToPrint )
```

So I tried this out:

```
protocol AProtocol {
   var value: Int
}
var myVarProtocol: AProtocol
myVarProtocol = 155
```

And I got the error

> :10:17: error: cannot assign a value of type 'Int' to a value of type 'AProtocol

What do I need to do to `AProtocol` to make the protocol work as a type (if I'm wording this correctly)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is to be expected, since you're making a variable that can store any type that conforms to your protocol, yet you're trying to assign it a type (`Int`) that does not.

You have to manually add conformance to `AProtocol` to `Int` in this case. Remember, you've defined a protocol that states that any type that conforms to it must implement a `value` variable, so you'll have to add a definition for `value` to any type you want to work here.

```
protocol AProtocol {
    var value: Int { get }
}

extension Int: AProtocol {
    var value: Int {
        return self
    }
}

var myVarProtocol: AProtocol
myVarProtocol = 155
print(myVarProtocol) // 155
```

Comment: Thanks, these are big steps for me...
Can you make this work for String/Double etc (overloaded) - like the Printable protocol?

Comment: @Bart Yes, but you have to add the conformance on a type by type basis. This is what is done internally as well. Add `import Swift` to your project and command-click "Swift". Here you can see all of the public declarations for the standard library, including where type like `String` and `Double` are explicitly made to conform to protocols like `Printable`.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful.
Can you add Double type as well to the example?? I use an online swift playground currently, so I have no access to Xcode (I'm saving money for a macBook).

Ahead, I'll mark the question answered :-)